# Convert from Base64 to Image, got an error "Parameter not valid"

Tags: c#, converters, image-conversion

I have a base64 image as SVG tag, I tried it on online converter and it works fine and image appears, but in code, it gets an error here:

```
image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

I don't know why? The base64 is correct!
My full method is:

```
public Image ConvertIntoBytes(string EncodedBase)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image image = null;
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(EncodedBase);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
                {
                    image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
            }
            return image;
        }
```

Note:
array bytes length: 15919

**EDIT**

The problem is SVG base64, so I tried to install "SVG Rendering" From Nuget.

Comment: The Image class does not know anything about SVG, it requires a properly encoded image in a format like PNG, BMP, JPEG.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, as I can see from question, decoding is OK. As mension before, `System.Drawing.Image` doesn't know what to do with SVG.

Comment: System.Drawing.Image doesn't support  SVG image format. You can see ImageFormat [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - yes it's not a particularly exciting or interesting question, but it's nonetheless valid, even though the answer is rather unfortunate.

Comment: I would start by removing the catch block - let the exception bubble up, and then include the stack trace in the question. That will make it clear whether the problem is with base64 decoding or (as expected by other comments) it's in `Image.FromStream`.

Comment: @HansPassant you're correct, i installed  "SVG Rendering Engine" to convert SVG to jpeg or png but i am still working on it but thank you anyway.

Comment: @Fatmaelzahraa Can you please add your solution? I am facing the same issue